# Windows IoT, get the number of processor's cores allocated for Soft Real Time

Tags: powershell, wmi, windowsiot

From the Microsoft documentation [soft-real-time-device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/soft-real-time/soft-real-time-device), we allocate the number of processor's cores to be allocated for Soft Real Time using the following PowerShell script:

```
$nameSpaceName="root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap"

$className="MDM_WindowsIoT_SoftRealTimeProperties01"

$obj = Get-CimInstance -Namespace $namespaceName -ClassName $className

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj

$obj.SetRTCores = 3

Set-CimInstance -CimInstance $obj
```

The number **3** in the script above is the number of cores allocated.
Is there anyway to read back that number? something like **$obj.GetRTCores**. I googled the method **SetRTCores**, but poorly occurence/documentation.

Comment: The link is fixed, sorry!

Comment: Did you manage to get an answer for this? thanks